# ASP.Net DataGrid not displaying Time dataType from dataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, datagrid

I have a form and a data grid on ASP page, I used the the following code to get the data displayed in the data grid, The code:

```
protected void getDataGrid()
{
  string strCon = "Data Source = OMEGA\\SQLEXPRESS2012; Initial Catalog = CPAMS; Integrated Security = SSPI;";
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
  string sqlCmd = "SELECT OrderInProgress.oInProgId AS 'Ord Prog ID', OrderInProgress.oInPDate AS 'Ord Prog Date',"
      + " OrderInProgress.OrderId AS 'Order ID', OrderInProgress.StartTime AS 'Start Time', "
      + " OrderInProgress.EndTime AS 'End Time', OrderInProgress.CCid AS 'Cost Center' FROM OrderInProgress;";
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, con);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  try
  {
    con.Open();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    dgJOP.DataSource = dt;
    dgJOP.DataBind();
  }
  catch (SqlException se)
  {
    MessageBox("Database error!");
    ExceptLog.ErrorLogging(se, se.ToString());
  }
  finally
  {
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
  }

}
```

Now the problem is that all data in sql table is displayed in the data grid except for Time data which is Start time and End time fields despite that both fields display values correctly in the form's text box.

The `html` code for the Data Grid is:

```
<div class="GridCont">

  <asp:DataGrid ID="dgJOM" runat="server" CssClass="dgCss">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="dgHeader" />
    <ItemStyle CssClass="dgItem" />
    <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="dgAltItem" />
  </asp:DataGrid>

</div>
```

I know it might be a problem with time format conversion in the grid but I am not sure, I have tried goggling a solution or explanation but in vain.

Comment: there are multiple ways to markup a grid. You should probably show how you are doing it. And, `MessageBox` on a web form????

Comment: The `MessageBox` is just a class I made to alert user with certain validations and instructions.